# Downloadable product links gone in 1.9.2

Tags: php, magento

[image]

Downloadable products and status not showing in my downloadable products from magento. Anyone face the same issue ?

Comment: Please ask your question properly, read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get solution for this problem:
copy and paste the below code in line no :60
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/customer/products/list.phtml

```
<td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getPurchased()->getProductName()) ?> - <a href="<?php echo $this->getDownloadUrl($_item) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('Start Download') ?>" <?php echo $this->getIsOpenInNewWindow()?'onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'"':''; ?>><?php echo $_item->getLinkTitle(); ?></a></td>
```